# Monochromatic Wave (Glitch Liquid)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, monochrome, glitch

I've been trying to find out how this effect has been made because I cant seem to get it done myself.

I tried creating liquid and glitching it, but that doesn't look like anything close to this haha Does anyone have an idea of how it might be done? It looks easy enough, but I just dont know where to start

[image: Glitchy Liquid]

Answer (score 1):

This has at least 3 layers when one makes it. In the bottom there's a quite regular dot pattern, like a photo of bubble wrap plastics.

In the middle there's a wave pattern where the RGB channel contents are shifted apart like in this older case: [How can I recreate this holographic iridescent water effect in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119066/how-can-i-recreate-this-holographic-iridescent-water-effect-in-photoshop)

On top there's a transparent yellowish color. Or there's an adjustment layer which reduces generally blue and increases green and red. Poor contrast suggests it's a transparent color layer.

Comment: Thank you!!!

you just made my day! I'll get on it right away, hopefully I can show you the result when I'm succesful haha!

Thanks for taking the time to figure it out!

Comment: @MwaniniMakangira - if this answers your question, you should choose it as best answer.